Find every generated mending book in 1000x1000 world
By generated mending book I mean chests and chest minecarts that generate in structures.
Is there an external tool that would allow this?
The /data command works only in loaded chunks, but more importantly it cannot read the chest contents before a player opens it and generates the loot. I couldn't think of anything else

fill … destroy might be able to help.

You're probably going to need to need to reverse engineer and reimplement the world and loot generation to quickly get that data you need. Alternatively, you could generate a 1000x1000 world, open every chest, then parse through it outside the game.

I don't see how this is answerable even in theory - if a chest hasn't been opened then it's undecided whether it contains a mending book - the dice haven't been rolled on whether it will.
